# Cytoscape multiple variable for style

Tags: cytoscape

I'm using Cytoscape for generating a regulatory network. Are there any option for using multiple variables to set  node size?

For example:

I have two groups A and B. The node size of the group be should be defined by the column 'expression' and the node size of the edgecount.

I try to select only the A nodes and set the node size by expression in styles but it change all the data set.

Comment: Can you specify how the node size is defined?  Is it dependent on the number of edges or the column expression, where is the column expression?

Comment: Also, please show us what you already tried (e.g your current code), that way, we can help you far better

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this in Cytoscape, but I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.  You could create a combination column, but generally using size for two different variables is likely to confuse the viewers.  I would suggest